# Else if Statement for Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I made a hybrid grid with content that gets populated through Advanced Custom Fields. Everything works ok, except that when I set up an if/else statement to go with the checkbox I set up in the ACF in WordPress admin, it causes a 500 error. This is the main block of code that has the if/else statement:

```
    <div class="watcheroos">
    <?php

    if(count($postslist) > 0) { ?>

    <ul class="list-unstyled">

    <?php 

        $clearfix_counter = 0;

        foreach ($new_list as $index => $post) { 

        $bkg_id =  get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        $bkg_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bkg_id, 'medium' );
        $bkg_src_lg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bkg_id, 'large' );  

        $network = get_post_meta($post->ID,'network',true);
        $timeofday = get_post_meta($post->ID,'time_of_day',true);
        $date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'date',true);
        $producer = get_post_meta($post->ID,'producer',true);


        if($index %8 == 0 || $index %9 == 0 || $index == 1 ) { ?>

            <?php if ($index == 0) { ?>

                <li class="watcheroo first <?php if($addClass){echo 'widewidth'; } ?>" id="<?php echo sanitize_title($post->post_title); ?>">

                    <div class="content" <?php if($bkg_src_lg[0]){ echo 'style="background-image: url(' . $bkg_src_lg[0] . ');"'; } ?> >

                    </div>
                    <div class="featured-info">
                        <h4><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="network"><strong>Network:</strong> <?php echo $network; ?></div>
                            <div class="timeofday"><strong>Time-of-day:</strong> <?php echo $timeofday; ?></div>
                            <div class="date"><strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $date; ?></div>
                            <div class="producer"><strong>Produced by:</strong> <?php echo $producer; ?></div>
                            <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
                            <?php 
                                $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'watcheroo_production_credits');
                                if($terms) {
                                    echo '<ul class="credits list-unstyled list-inline">'; 
                                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                        echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</ul>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>



            <?php } elseif(get_field('wide_box')): { ?>

                <li class="watcheroo wider" id="<?php echo sanitize_title($post->post_title); ?>">
                    <div class="content" <?php if($bkg_src_lg[0]){ echo 'style="background-image: url(' . $bkg_src_lg[0] . ');"'; } ?> >
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <div class="network"><strong>Network:</strong> <?php echo $network; ?></div>
                                    <div class="timeofday"><strong>Time-of-day:</strong> <?php echo $timeofday; ?></div>
                                    <div class="date"><strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $date; ?></div>
                                    <div class="producer"><strong>Produced by:</strong> <?php echo $producer; ?></div>
                                    <?php //echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="expanded-content">
                        <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
                        <?php 
                            $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'watcheroo_production_credits');
                            if($terms) {
                                echo '<ul class="credits list-unstyled list-inline">'; 
                                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                    echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
                                }
                                echo '</ul>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </li>   

            <?php }

        } else { ?>

            <li class="watcheroo <?php if($addClass){echo 'widewidth'; } ?>" id="<?php echo sanitize_title($post->post_title); ?>">
                <div class="content" <?php if($bkg_src[0]){ echo 'style="background-image: url(' . $bkg_src[0] . ');"'; } ?> >
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
                            <div class="info">
                                <div class="network"><strong>Network:</strong> <?php echo $network; ?></div>
                                <div class="timeofday"><strong>Time-of-day:</strong> <?php echo $timeofday; ?></div>
                                <div class="date"><strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $date; ?></div>
                                <div class="producer"><strong>Produced by:</strong> <?php echo $producer; ?></div>
                                <?php //echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="expanded-content">
                    <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
                    <?php 
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'watcheroo_production_credits');
                        if($terms) {
                            echo '<ul class="credits list-unstyled list-inline">'; 
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>

        <?php } 

    } ?>    

    </ul>

     <div class="clearfix"></div>

       <?php } endif; ?>

     </div>

     </div>

     <?php foreach ($postslist as $post) { 

        $network = get_post_meta($post->ID,'network',true);
        $timeofday = get_post_meta($post->ID,'time_of_day',true);
        $date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'date',true);
        $producer = get_post_meta($post->ID,'producer',true);
        $bkg_id =  get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        $bkg_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bkg_id, 'medium' ); 

    ?> 

      <div id="<?php echo $post->ID . '-' . sanitize_title($post->post_title); ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalwindow">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body"> 
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <?php if($bkg_src[0]){ ?><img class="alignleft" src="<?php echo $bkg_src[0]; ?>" /><?php } ?> 
        <h1 class="modal-title"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h1>
        <div class="network"><strong>Network:</strong> <?php echo $network; ?></div>
        <div class="timeofday"><strong>Time-of-day:</strong> <?php echo $timeofday; ?></div>
        <div class="date"><strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $date; ?></div>
        <div class="producer"><strong>Produced by:</strong> <?php echo $producer; ?></div>
        <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <?php } ?>
```

Am I placing the endif; in the wrong spot? I tried placing it in different spots, please any help would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing two types of if/else statements

```
<?php } elseif(get_field('wide_box')): { ?>
```

should be

```
<?php } else if ( get_field('wide_box') ) { ?>
```

and

```
<?php } endif; ?>
```

should just be

```
<?php } ?>
```